# Manipulate a series of DataFrames Dynamically

Tags: python, dataframe, list, range

I am trying to manipulate a series of DataFrames dynamically.  For example, I want to multiply the DataFrames (‘recs_df’ – below) by a another DataFrame of values (‘Cost’ – below):

```
  recs_df1:
         Prod      Ord1  Ord2  Ord3
    0    Toys       4      2    1
    1    Candy      3      1    5
    2    Décor      2      3    4
    
   recs_df2:
         Prod      Ord1  Ord2  Ord3
    0    Toys       1     0     6
    1    Candy      4     1     5
    2    Décor      2     3     4
    
   recs_df3:
         Prod      Ord1  Ord2  Ord3
    0    Toys       1     2     3
    1    Candy      0     1     0
    2    Décor      1     3     4
    
    cost_df:
         Prod    Price
    0    Toys    2.00
    1    Candy   1.00
    2    Décor   3.00


The desired outcome is 3 new DataFrames formed by the product of the Cost_df to each of the recs#_df, i.e.:

new_df1:
0    Toys        8.00       4.00     2.00    
1    Candy       3.00       1.00     5.00
2    Décor       6.00       9.00     12.00

new_df2:     
0    Toys       2.00      0.00       12.00
1    Candy      4.00      1.00        5.00
2    Décor      6.00      9.00       12.00


new_df3:
0    Toys       2.00       4.00        6.00
1    Candy      0.00       1.00        0.00
2    Décor      3.00       9.00       12.00
```

I have tried setting up a list of DataFrames, as well as just looping through them directly, and I always get errors – for example:

```
df_list = [recs_df1, recs_df2, recs_df3]
for df in df_list:
    new_df.append(cost_df*df_list)

new_dfs  = [ ]
for j in range(3):
   for i in range(0,len(recs_df[j].index)):
          new=append((cost_df*df_list[j])
   new_dfs=pd.DataFrame(new)
```

Clearly, I am confused.  I welcome your advice – Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It simplifies things a bit if you do the common column as the index:

```
recs_df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Ord1':[4, 3, 2], 
     'Ord2': [2, 1, 3], 
     'Ord3': [1, 5, 4]},
    index=['Toys', 'Candy', 'Décor'])
recs_df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Ord1':[1, 4, 2], 
     'Ord2': [0, 1, 3], 
     'Ord3': [6, 5, 4]},
    index=['Toys', 'Candy', 'Décor'])
recs_df3 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Ord1':[1, 0, 1], 
     'Ord2': [2, 1, 3], 
     'Ord3': [3., 0, 4]},
    index=['Toys', 'Candy', 'Décor'])
costs_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Price': [2., 1., 3.]}, index=['Toys', 'Candy', 'Décor'])

dfs = [recs_df1, recs_df2, recs_df3]
new_dfs = []

for df in dfs:
    new_df = df.copy()
    for col in new_df:
        new_df[col] = new_df[col] * costs_df.Price
        new_dfs.append(new_df)
```

But this can be simplified by converting prices to numpy:

```
new_dfs = [costs_df.to_numpy() *  df for df in dfs]
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do this dynamically? - as the number of dataFrames I have is much larger than three -- say 100+.  As well, the number of dataFrames can change over time.

Comment: Yes...? Just have whatever aspect of your code creates the dataframe also append it to your list.